# Access Trello programmatically using OAuth

Tags: trello, authentication, oauth

I'm currently trying to access a private Trello board using a Node.js web application. What I want to achieve is to create new cards. Unfortunately, I'm stuck in the process of receiving a token.

I use the node-oath library and embed it as follows:

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth,
    oauth = new OAuth('https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken',
                      'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken',
                      myKey,
                      myOAuthSecret,
                      '1.0',
                      undefined,
                      'PLAINTEXT');
```

Afterwards, I try to get a token by calling:

```
oauth.getOAuthRequestToken(function (error, oauth_token, oauth_secret, results) {
  if (error) return console.log('1: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    oauth.getOAuthAccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_secret, function (error, oauth_access_token, oauth_access_token_secret, access_results) {
      if (error) return console.log('2: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      // ...
```

When I run this code, I always get the following error message:

```
1: {"statusCode":500,"data":"Invalid Signature"}
```

So, obviously there is something wrong with the first OAuth request. I've seen that Trello also supports HMAC-SHA1. When I use it instead of PLAINTEXT, the first request succeeds, but the second fails as I have not specified an oauth_verifier.

Unfortunately I do not have the slightest idea of how to provide this verifier. I've read the [OAuth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849), but that didn't really help me.

Basically, I do not actually *need* HMAC-SHA1, PLAINTEXT would be fine.

Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong?

PS: I've read on the Trello developer board that once there was a bug which did not allow Trello to access the key sent within the body, so they advised you to send it using the query string. But even if I change the first codeblock to

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth,
    oauth = new OAuth('https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken?key=' + myKey,
                      'https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken',
                      myKey,
                      myOAuthSecret,
                      '1.0',
                      undefined,
                      'PLAINTEXT');
```

it doesn't change anything at all :-/

Any ideas?

Comment: The call to `getOAuthAccessToken` should have the `oauth_verifier` as the third argument, which you get when a user logs in and is redirected back to you.  There doesn't appear to be anywhere in this flow for the user to log in, which is a problem.

Comment: Okay - but what if the login should be done completely automatically? I don't want a popup to be opened and the user being asked for credentials or confirmation or something like that.

Comment: OAuth doesn't work like that.  It requires the user to give permission.  Maybe if you explain the use-case we can figure something out.

Comment: Well, basically the use case is as follows: I'd like to write a plugin for a CRM system that automatically creates cards in Trello when something in the CRM happens. As this action is triggered from the backend, and you do not even have a browser at hand, it's hard to redirect the user somewehere ... any ideas?

Comment: Your best bet is to create a user that performs actions on behalf of the CRM.  Then, just get a key/token pair from [here](https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate) and use those to make requests (just put them in the request data).  For what you're trying to do, OAuth isn't the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node-trello package from npm (linked below) is oauth'ing fine for me, and I didn't find any problems with your code by inspection; what I would do if I were you would be to install node-trello and use that as a working example; if that doesn't work, then maybe you need to re-generate your developer key.

**node-trello:**

https://github.com/adunkman/node-trello

https://github.com/adunkman/node-trello/blob/master/lib/trello-oauth.coffee

Comment: This is what I already use, and that's exactly the problem: node-trello asks me for a token - where do I get this from, _WITHOUT_ asking the user to interact?

Comment: That's really the only way for the user to authorize the app with Trello; Trello has to be able to say 'hey, we're about to allow this app to look at (and possibly modify) non-public information in your account; is that ok?' Security-wise, it would be difficult to get around that requirement.